# Command prefixes in Python CLI using cmd in Python's standard library

Tags: python, interface, command, line

I'm attempting to create a CLI for a IRC client that I am writing using nothing but standard python packages. I have been using the native cmd library in python, an it works quite well for my needs (for now), but there is one issue that I haven't been able to fix.

There is a public instance variable for the inclusion of a command prefix in the cmd library, but I cannot for the life of me get it to work correctly; it just gives me an "Unknown syntax" error. The goal here is ' /help ' or other commands with the / prefix would call that method, and simply typing ' help ' would send "help" to the server.

Here is the in progress CLI class in my code:

```
class lircCLI(Cmd):

    intro = 'Welcome to LIRC \nType help or ? for command list'
    prompt = 'lirc> '
    identchars = '/'   << the problem 


     #---------commands-----------

    def do_sync(self):
        'Force synchronize with the IRC server'
        connectionHandler.syncMessages()

    def do_whoami(self, arg):
        'Good question'
        print(user.getName())

    def do_changename(self, arg):
         'Change your name'
         user.setName(arg)
         print("Username has been changed to '"+user.name+"'")

    def default(self, line):
         'Sends a message'
         #compiles message request
         message = str(user.getName().replace(" ", "_") + " SHOUTS " + line + " END")
         connectionHandler.sendMessage(message)
         logHandler.updateChatLog({time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") : {'time': time.strftime("%I:%M:%S"), 'user': user.getName(),'text': line}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `identchars` property actually defines the character set from which commands may be drawn. Its default value is pretty much "ascii chars".

What you want to do instead is use the `.precmd` method to reverse the normal processing. Look for a leading slash, and if found strip it. If not found, prepend some invalid prefix or some "default" command name. Either of these could work:

```
def precmd(self, line):
    if line[0] == '/':
        line = line[1:]
    else:
        line = '>' + line
    return line

def default(self, line):
    line = line[1:]
    print("You said, '"+line+"'")
```

Or alternatively:

```
def precmd(self, line):
    if line[0] == '/':
        line = line[1:]
    else:
        line = 'say ' + line
    return line

def do_say(self, arg):
    print("You said, '"+arg+"'")

def default(self, line):
    raise ValueError("Inconceivable!")
```

Comment: Ah okay, my interpretation of that variable was way off. Thanks for the solutions also!